# background to BorderPane javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx, background

I made a UI stage.
and I have a `BorderPane` in the stage.
now, I want to add a bacgGround Image to `layout`

I want to use CSS but it doesn't work

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    carStage = new Stage();
    BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
    carScene = new Scene(layout);
    carStage.setTitle("רכב");
    GridPane center = new GridPane();
    enterFieldsToCenter(center);
    right(layout);
    layout.setCenter(center);
    layout.setStyle("style.css");
    carStage.setScene(carScene);
    layout.getCenter().setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"C:\\Users\\itayz\\eclipse-workspace\\Itay'sCar\\src\\CrystalClear.jpg\");"
            + "-fx-background-size: 500, 500;"
            + "-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;");

    sizeOfStage();
    carStage.show();

}
```

the background is from : https://uigradients.com/#CrystalClear
how can I import it easily?

Note: the file exist in the path

Comment: You could try `url("/CrystalClear.jpg");` (see [this documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl)). But why not use a [`LinearGradient`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html) to set the background to the linked-to color (can also be done [via CSS](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepaint))?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your URI has no scheme.

From to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeuri):

> `url ( [\"\']? <address> [\"\']? )`
>
> `<address>` can be an absolute URI, for example:
>
> - `url(http://example.com)`
> - `url('http://example.com')`
> - `url("http://example.com")`
>
> or it can be relative to the location of the CSS file.

So you have to use an absolute URL with scheme:

```
layout.getCenter().setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/Users/itayz/eclipse-workspace/Itay'sCar/src/CrystalClear.jpg\");"
        + "-fx-background-size: 500, 500;"
        + "-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;");
```

Beside that I would recommend to use a relative URL and place the image in your project resources.

Comment: I updated my question, it seems I forgot a `/`. Can you try again?

Comment: the error:    Mar 18, 2019 11:04:59 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager getCachedImage
WARNING: Error loading image: file:/C:Usersitayzeclipse-workspaceItay'sCarsrcCrystalClear.jpg

Comment: @ItayZemah can you try using using `/` instead of `\ ` as file separator. As I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern worked for me:

```
-fx-background-image: url('file:C:/Data/example.jpg');
```

So, in your case it would be:

```
layout.getCenter().setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('file:C:/Users/itayz/eclipse-workspace/Itay'sCar/src/CrystalClear.jpg');"
                                    + "-fx-background-size: 500, 500;"
                                    + "-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;");
```

Comment: Mar 20, 2019 11:38:24 AM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser term
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-background-image: url('file:C:/Users/itayz/eclipse-workspace/Itay'sCar/src/CrystalClear.jpg');-fx-background-size: 500, 500;-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;}: Unexpected token 'file:C:/Users/itayz/eclipse-workspace/Itay' at [1,24]

Comment: It probably has to do with your path. I expect the apostrophe is the problem. You propably have to escape it (\').